# How to use greater than to compare enum values?

Tags: typescript, enums, comparison

Given the following enum

```
enum Verbosity {
  quiet = -1,
  normal = 0,
  verbose = 1,
  veryVerbose = 2,
  debug = 3,
}
```

How can I use `greater than` in a condition?

The condition in below example always returns false.

```
const verbosity = 2;
log.verbosity = Verbosity[verbosity];

if (log.verbosity > Verbosity.normal) {
  log.debug('Verbosity:', log.verbosity);
}
```

What is the correct syntax for using greater than if any?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I made the mistake of parsing `2` to an `Enum key` instead of an `Enum value`.

Additionally, Deno was parsing the condition as false instead of throwing the [expected](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAasBOAjA9gZwJYBcCeUDeAUFFAI5jrCZQC8UAtAIwA0RUIy8EAhgDY1QAGFsQBuCFKmD9mrMfGxwkaKbQBMwqABNgiMAHN+AZhYBfAgQDGyEKipyJWXGoDc5qzargIAfXtpH-IoOOADafhg4ALquBOgAZlAAFF6+4v44UAB8sGkR2AB07Jy8AJT4rO6oyDzA+TzIeokA5EHp2ABcTUxskKlKeSWuZkA) error:

> Operator '>' cannot be applied to types 'string' and 'Verbosity'.

The following works as expected

```
const verbosity = 2;

log.verbosity = Verbosity[Verbosity[verbosity]];

if (log.verbosity > Verbosity.normal) {
  log.debug('Verbosity:', Verbosity[log.verbosity]); // Output: Verbosity: veryVerbose
}
```